# C# LINQ orderby on a single slot of an object array

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I have a function that return a `List<object[]>`. I would like to group by the first slot in the object and sort by the 2nd. I have gotten the group part to work but can't seem to get sort syntax correct. The code below correctly groups the result. I would like each individual group to be sorted by date (2nd slot of oject[]). Does anyone know the syntax for this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;    
namespace Linq_Object_Array_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            List<object[]> data = new List<object[]>();    
            data.Add(new object[3] { "6752 JT", new DateTime(2011, 1, 12), 3690 });
            data.Add(new object[3] { "6752 JT", new DateTime(2011, 1, 13), 3600 });
            data.Add(new object[3] { "7630 JT", new DateTime(2011, 1, 11), 789 });
            data.Add(new object[3] { "6752 JT", new DateTime(2011, 1, 11), 3694 });
            data.Add(new object[3] { "7630 JT", new DateTime(2011, 1, 12), 780 });
            data.Add(new object[3] { "7630 JT", new DateTime(2011, 1, 13), 769 });
            data.Add(new object[3] { "8719 JT", new DateTime(2011, 1, 11), 43200 });

            // correctly groups by symbol of security
            var query = data.GroupBy(o => o[0]);

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.Write(item.Key.ToString() + "\n");    
                foreach (var item2 in item)                    
                    Console.Write("  {0}  {1}  {2} \n", item2[0].ToString(), item2[1].ToString(), item2[2].ToString());      
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The [Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) extension is what you seek:

```
var query = data.OrderBy(o => o[1]).GroupBy(o => o[0]);
```

Comment: Well that is embarrassing. I had group and orderby reversed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would really consider using an anonymous type (or create a separate class) instead of using `List<Object>`. That will give you more readable code and type safety.

Like this:

```
var data = new[]{
new { Id = "6752 JT", Date = new DateTime(2011, 1, 12), Num = 3690 },
new { Id = "6752 JT", Date = new DateTime(2011, 1, 13), Num = 3600 },
...,
};

var query = data.OrderBy(o => o.Date).GroupBy(o => o.Id);
```